# Previous button with React when the url doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

**CONTEXT** : I am building a form with hooks. There is one question for one page and **the next question is displayed depending on the previous answer**. I work with redux so I can't change the url (otherwise all anwers are deleted). Next questions are pushed with a function "switchQuestions()". The function get the answers from redux and return the component with the right question.

**PROBLEM** : I want to display a previous question but I don't know how.

**CODE** : Here is an example of how looks my switchQuestion() function :

```
 function switchQuestion1() {
if (answers.question9bis === 'Seul' || answers.question9bis === 'A deux') {
  return (
    <Question29 activeStep={activeStep} setActiveStep={setActiveStep} />
  );
}
if (
  (answers.question8bis === 'Propriétaire' ||
    answers.question8bis === 'Bénéficiaire d un logement de fonction' ||
    answers.question8bis === 'Hébergé à titre gratuit' ||
    answers.question8bisa !== '') &&
  // TODO test pour ne pas avoir 2 fois la réponse à la question9
  answers.question9 === ''
) {
  return <Question9bis />;
}
if (answers.question8bis === 'Locataire') {
  return <Question8bisa />;
}
if (answers.question18 === 'Non' || answers.question18a !== '') {
  return <Question8bis />;
}
if (answers.question18 === 'Oui') {
  return <Question18a />;
}
if (answers.question17 !== '') {
  return <Question18 />;
}
```

Comment: Could you properly elaborate your question. Do you need to render views based on redux change which is invoked by the current mounted view ?

Comment: Here is how I render the next question. But I want to have a previous button but I don't know how...

Comment: basically you need to maintain the previous question data also on the redux store and use it with the current mounted component